# Can't drag window in pygame after closing tkinter.filedialog

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pygame, environment-variables

I have used **Tkinter** with my project in **pygame** and I have faced the next issue,
 just for the note I have to write the next code to show briefly the problem I am facing.
I have bound the left mouse click to open the filedialog then return the name of a file, after that when I click the window, the top bar of the window changes its color and I can't drag it.

```
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk
import pygame as pg

def openf():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)
    root.withdraw()
    file = filedialog.askopenfile(filetypes=[("Text file", "*.txt")], defaultextension=[("Text file", "*.txt")])
    return file.name

def main():
    pg.init()
    fname="File"
    screen=pg.display.set_mode((400,400))
    going=True
    font=pg.font.Font(pg.font.get_default_font(),30)
    txt=font.render(fname,True,(255,255,255))
    press = 0
    while going:
        posx,posy=pg.mouse.get_pos()
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if pg.QUIT==event.type:
                going=False
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                press=event.button

        if(press==3):
            fname=openf()
            txt = font.render(fname, True, (255, 255, 255))
            print(fname)
            press=0
        screen.fill((255,100,234))
        text = font.render("x = " + str(posx) + "y = " + str(posy), True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(text, (100, 200))

        screen.blit(txt,(100,100))

        pg.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

just for notice that before doing that the program doesn't take the coordinate of x and y if the mouse outside the main window and in the upper bar, but after calling the filedialog it takes the coordinate

> Image of the program:
> : https://drive.google.com/file/d/17tQSVmzUvwEyB_jXVxFQ-6BAm_NwS82m/view?usp=sharing

Comment: not sure, wat the issue is. but try removing this `root.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)`

Comment: I tested the code you posted. It seems to work correctly. After selecting the file, the file name displays on the screen and I can move the mouse again with the program displaying the coordinates.

Comment: @Mike67 , Yes you can, but try to click over any point inside the program then try to drag the window then You will see the issue

Comment: @CoolCloud I have already tried to but it didn't work

Comment: could be, cause you are using pygame and tkinter, im not sure, just saying. and @Mike67 dint have any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also noticed with your code that after the dialog closes and you click on the window, your app captures the mouse for the entire screen. I can click anywhere and the dialog will open again. Possibly a tkinter issue.

After some trial and error, it looks like you just need to reset you pygame screen after using tkinter. This will reset your mouse.

```
 if(press==3):
     fname=openf()  # open file dialog (tkinter)
     screen=pg.display.set_mode((400,400))  # reset pygame screen
     txt = font.render(fname, True, (255, 255, 255))
     print(fname)
     press=0
```